# Browserify ES6 - Dynamic Requires

Tags: javascript, browserify, ecmascript-6

I am looking to create a Modules system within my Application. I'm unsure on how to implement the following:

**Module 1**

```
class SomethingModule {

}

export default SomethingModule;
```

**Module 2**

```
class SomethingElseModule {

}

export default SomethingElseModule;
```

**Module Loader**

```
class ModuleLoader {

    load(module) {
        // "module" could be "Something" which should create a
        // new instance of "SomethingModule"
        module = module + 'Module';
        // Require and create an instance of "module"
    }

}

export default ModuleLoader;
```

**Main File**

```
var ModuleLoader = require('./ModuleLoader');

var loader = new ModuleLoader();
loader.load('SomethingElse');
```

I'm pretty new to modularised JavaScript and have no idea if this is even possible/feasible. If not, is there a way of doing this you'd suggest without polluting the global namespace and referencing `window[moduleName]`?

Comment: why do you want to use global namespace? 
i'd suggest to require in your "module loader" file the modules

Comment: @bln I don't, that's the point. And requiring the individual Modules in the `ModuleLoader` is exactly what I'm trying to find an alternative to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, you can create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and load your module in there:

```
class ModuleLoader {
    constructor() {
        this._modules = new Map();
    }

    load(module) {
        // you should check if the module exist in a good world to not get any error
       // and probably adjust the path of what you are requiring
        this._modules.set(module, new require(`${module}Module`));
    }

    getModuleByName(name) {
        return this._modules.get(name);
    }

}
```

**Edit:** To make it work with `browserify`, you will need to have this list of all the modules somewhere. You can create a separate file `ModuleBag` like this:

```
//moduleBag.js
import yourModule from './yourModule';
import yourSecondModule from './yourSecondModule';

var map = new Map();
map.set('yourModule', yourModule);
map.set('yourSecondModule', yourSecondModule);

export default class map;

//moduleLoader.js
import moduleBag from './moduleBag';
class ModuleLoader {
        constructor() {
            this._modules = new Map();
        }
    
        load(module) {
            var mod = moduleBag.get(module);
            this._modules.set(module, new mod());
        }
    
        getModuleByName(name) {
            return this._modules.get(name);
        }
    
    }
```

or just put it in the same file.
With this, `browserify` will be able to load all the necessary files.

Comment: And this would work with Browserify? As the `require` is dynamic, would it be compiled by Browserify?